# 404 Error for http//

Tags: 2013, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm getting the below error for our root domain and all subsites when they are typed in the format http://domain.co.uk or https://domain.co.uk

> HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

We have a rewrite rule in place which works fine for http://www.domain.co.uk, but can someone please tell me what's wrong and why it's not redirecting both http://domain.co.uk and https://domain.co.uk to https://www.domain.co.uk?

We're using SharePoint 2013 on premise.

```
 <rule name="Force WWW and SSL" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^[^www]" />
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
    </conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://www.domain.co.uk/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to a Windows patch [KB4498206](https://support.microsoft.com/help/4498206/cumulative-security-update-for-internet-explorer-may-14-2019) and/or [KB4499164](https://support.microsoft.com/help/4499164/windows-7-update-kb4499164).

I believe these were addressed in subsequent patches but have not verified. I believe they may impact more than Windows 7 as well, but again have not verified.

The issue here was that Microsoft added the domain `co.uk` to the HSTS list in Internet Explorer, forcing `co.uk` sites to use SSL and not HTTP.

Comment: It looks like the second patch added the domain `gov.uk` to the HSTS list, not `co.uk`. I also forgot to add that this is on Windows Server 2012 R2.